# dynamically created link click event firing but the delete function is not doing the desired effect

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

hi i am playing with the gridview and the autocomplete function of jqueryui i am adding rows to a gridview dynamically after clicking an item on an autocomplete returned items here is the code:

```
$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/web.asmx/hello")%>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },


                select: function (e, i) {
                    //$("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);

                    var row;

                        var totalRows = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID()%> tr").length;

                        if (totalRows <= 1) {
                            $('#GridView1 tbody tr:first').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                        }

                        if (row == null) {
                            row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                        }

                        $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
                        $("td", row).eq(0).html(i.item.val);
                        $("td", row).eq(1).html(i.item.label);
                        $("td", row).eq(2).html('<a href=# class=delbutton id=' + i.item.val + '>' + 'DELETE' + '</a>');
                        $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);


                    }

                },
                minLength: 1
            });
```

and here is my delete function:

```
$('#GridView1').on('click' , '.delbutton' , function (){
                var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var tr_id = $(this).parents(".record");

                if (confirm('remove?')) {
                    tr_id.css("background-color", "lightgreen");
                    // Do some animation effect

                    tr_id.fadeOut(500, function () {

                        //Remove GridView row

                        tr_id.remove();


                    });
                } else {
                    alert('canceled');
                }
            });
```

the delete function is working well but when the first rows is deleted and il add new through clicking on a autocomplete returned data the delete function still works but the actual deletion of the row is not working

what am i doing wrong?

any suggestion would be very helpful

thank you

Comment: my guess is because your first row already has the "record" class added, but when you add the rows dynamically you leave out the "record" class. The new rows would fail to be selected because you're selecting the row to delete with $(".record"). You will need to fix the selector that is invoked to capture the tr_id variable.

Comment: you nailed it great thank you for the quick response you should post the answer for me to vote on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is because your first row already has the "record" class added, but when you add the rows dynamically you leave out the "record" class.

The new rows would fail to be deleted because you're selecting the row to delete with $(".record").

You will need to fix the selector that is invoked to capture the tr_id variable.